# DataGrid inside ContentControl, which uses ContentTemplateSelector

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, contentcontrol

I am current trying to build a form that displays different datagrids with different columns and data based on an input. I am selecting the appropriate DataTemplate and the columns show up correctly. I am binding the DataContext to the ContentControl. However, the data do not show up in the DataGrid.
Here's one of the templates in the app.xaml file.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="templateHola1" DataType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Savings">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Savings}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Total Income">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding TotalIncome}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Here's the form

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:HolaContentTemplateSelector x:Key="contentTemplateSelector" />
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <ComboBox SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged_1" DropDownClosed="ComboBox_DropDownClosed_1">
        <ComboBoxItem>Content 1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Content 2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Content 3</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <ContentControl x:Name="ctrAbc" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource contentTemplateSelector}" />

    <TextBox Text="{Binding Savings}" />
</StackPanel>
```

The last TextBox binding works, while the DataGrid bindings do not. Please illuminate me.

Edit

Savings and TotalIncome are properties in a class, whose list is used as the data source.

```
public class NetIncome : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int totalIncome = 5000;
    private int rent = 2000;
    private int food = 0;
    private int misc = 0;
    private int savings = 0;
    public NetIncome()
    {
        savings = totalIncome - (rent + food + misc);
    }

    public int TotalIncome
    {
        get
        {
            return totalIncome;
        }
        set
        {
            if (TotalIncome != value)
            {
                totalIncome = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TotalIncome");
            }
        }
    }
    public int Rent
    {
        get
        {
            return rent;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Rent != value)
            {
                rent = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Rent");
                UpdateSavings();
            }
        }
    }
    public int Food
    {
        get
        {
            return food;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Food != value)
            {
                food = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Food");
                UpdateSavings();
            }
        }
    }
    public int Misc
    {
        get
        {
            return misc;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Misc != value)
            {
                misc = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Misc");
                UpdateSavings();
            }
        }
    }
    public int Savings
    {
        get
        {
            return savings;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Savings != value)
            {
                savings = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Savings");
                UpdateSavings();
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateSavings()
    {
        Savings = TotalIncome - (Rent + Misc + Food);
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post come code of what "Savings" and "TotalIncome" are?

Comment: Maybe the problem is inside HolaContentTemplateSelector?

Comment: You shouldn't need to have a DataTemplateSelector at all. Instead, set the correct `DataType` of your different DataTemplates, and don't set an `x:Key` on them. The `DataType` should not be `ContentControl`, but the actual type of the content that is to be shown in the ContentControl. Moreover, `DataContext="{Binding}"` is usually redundant, as the DataContext is inherited by the DataGrid.

Comment: @HeorhiyPavlovych HolaContentTemplateSelector returns the correct datatemplate. I have tried using DataTemplateSelector with listview and everything works fine. It seems like the problem is with ContentControl but I don't know what.

Comment: @Pelicer I added the code that contains Savings and TotalIncome. They are just properties in a model class, whose list is used as data context.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for you input. Are you saying that I should use some control other than `ContentControl`? If so, what should I use? My main is to display `DataGrid`s of different columns and data based on the data binding.

Comment: Of course not, use a ContentControl. However, do not set its ContentTemplateSelecter property. Selection of the correct DataTemplate works automatically, when you only set their DataType.